# MonkeyRunner script go to 'Developer options' then check 'Stay Awake' but is not recorded

Tags: android, settings, monkeyrunner, android-developer-api

I am doing a **MonkeyRunner script** that sets some **settings** in the android settings menu. The problem is that when I go to **developer options**, I need to check **'Stay Awake' and 'Allow mock locations'** but when the script is finished these two are not checked anymore.

It seems that the device doesn't allow to change some settings through adb because when I do it manually it works.

```
device.touch(406, 336, "DOWN_AND_UP")

MonkeyRunner.sleep(2.0)

img = device.takeSnapshot().getSubImage((0, 300, 450, 80))

img.writeToFile(afterImg)

MonkeyRunner.sleep(2.0)
```

This is the part of the code that click on 'Stay Awake' and get an image of the result. The image show that the button is clicked. But after the script if I go back manualy I can see that 'Stay Awake' is unchecked.

Comment: provide your code for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: this is the part of my code where the problem happens.

Comment: I tried a script automatically generated by [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) (using the UI) and it works as expected. *Stay awake* stays if you go back or exit.

Comment: @dtmilano thanks for the comment. I also tried a script using AndroidViewClient and it works for Stay awake. The problem was certainly coming from MonkeyRunner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from MonkeyRunner. I recomend to use @dtmilano tool [AndroidVIewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki) that is easier to use than MonkeyRunner. This tool solved my problem.